# How to pass parameters to Restlet using the GWT client

Tags: gwt, restlet-2.0

I tried following the "[first application](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html#dsy303-restlet_gwt)" sample from Restlet using the GWT client, but my parameters are not being passed from the client to the server.

server interface:

```
public interface SeriesResource {
    @Get
    public ArrayList<SeriesPoint> getSeries(String pair, int barSize, int numBars, long toDate);
}
```

server impl:

```
public class SeriesServerResource extends ServerResource implements SeriesResource {
    @Get
    public ArrayList<SeriesPoint> getSeries(String pair, int barSize, int numBars, long toDate) {
        ...
    }
}
```

client:

```
public interface SeriesResourceProxy extends ClientProxy {
    @Get
    public void getSeries(String pair, int barSize, int numBars, long toDate, Result<ArrayList<SeriesPoint>> callback);
}
```

I checked the generated code for SeriesResourceProxyImpl.java to see what it is doing with the parameters, but its actually not doing anything with them which explains why they are not being sent to the server.  Is there something else I need to do in order to have the compiler generate the required code to submit my parameters?